# Issues with systemctl launching service

Tags: pi-3b+, home-automation, systemd

I have followed various tutorials to get `systemd` to launch Homebridge on my Pi. This is the main one which seems to have worked for many others: https://timleland.com/setup-homebridge-to-start-on-bootup/

When my Pi boots, running `top` etc doesn't show that the process is running. Upon asking for the status, I can see a chunk of Homebridge's log which indicates something has gone wrong.

```
pi@raspberrypi:/var/log $ systemctl status homebridge
● homebridge.service - Node.js HomeKit Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/homebridge.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2019-01-12 14:10:22 AEDT; 5min ago
 Main PID: 289 (homebridge)
   CGroup: /system.slice/homebridge.service
           └─289 homebridge

Jan 12 14:10:29 raspberrypi homebridge[289]:   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
Jan 12 14:10:29 raspberrypi homebridge[289]:   hostname: 'my.tado.com',
Jan 12 14:10:29 raspberrypi homebridge[289]:   host: 'my.tado.com',
Jan 12 14:10:29 raspberrypi homebridge[289]:   port: 443 }
Jan 12 14:10:29 raspberrypi homebridge[289]: [1/12/2019, 2:10:29 PM] [Tado AC] XXX - Error Getting Temperature Unit - XXX
Jan 12 14:10:29 raspberrypi homebridge[289]: [1/12/2019, 2:10:29 PM] [Tado AC] xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Jan 12 14:10:29 raspberrypi homebridge[289]: [1/12/2019, 2:10:29 PM] [Tado AC] Can't finish Tado Installation
Jan 12 14:10:29 raspberrypi homebridge[289]: [1/12/2019, 2:10:29 PM] [Tado AC] Please check you config and restart homebridge
Jan 12 14:10:29 raspberrypi homebridge[289]: [1/12/2019, 2:10:29 PM] [Tado AC] If the problem persist, plese open Issue at https://github.com/nitaybz/homebridge-tado-ac/issues
Jan 12 14:10:29 raspberrypi homebridge[289]: [1/12/2019, 2:10:29 PM] [Tado AC] xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The strange part for me is, when I start the process myself, the errors go away and Homebridge starts as expected.

```
$ sudo systemctl start homebridge
```

When I run `systemctl cat homebridge.service`, I get the contents of my service file:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/var/homebridge $ systemctl cat homebridge.service
# /etc/systemd/system/homebridge.service
[Unit]
Description=Node.js HomeKit Server 
After=syslog.target network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=homebridge
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/homebridge
ExecStart=/usr/bin/homebridge $HOMEBRIDGE_OPTS
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what might be different in the boot scenario?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of this command: `systemctl cat homebridge.service`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was wrong. `systemctl` *was* actually launching my service, it was just too early. It seems obvious now, but the issue was that there was no active internet connection ready in order for the executable to run properly.

Even though my Homebridge service file specified `network-online.target` in `After`, it was being started before an internet connection came up. I tried a whole spread of different suggestions on how to hold off on starting my service until the right time, but nothing ended up working.

I ended up making my own shell script to wait for an active connection to come live.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Commencing access lock..."

result=0
alt_fault=""
while [ $result -eq 0 ] 
do
    case "$(curl -s --max-time 2 -I http://google.com | sed 's/^[^ ]*  *\([0-9]\).*/\1/; 1q')" in
        [23]) echo "HTTP connectivity is up"; result=1;;
        5) alt_fault="The web proxy won't let us through";;
        *) alt_fault="The network is down or very slow";;
    esac
done

echo "Obtained connection"
```

I then added this script as a pre script to my service, by changing my service file to look like this. Note the one change.

```
[Unit]
Description=Node.js HomeKit Server 
After=syslog.target network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=homebridge
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/homebridge

ExecStartPre=/tado_internet_test.sh

ExecStart=/usr/bin/homebridge $HOMEBRIDGE_OPTS
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The service is now appropriately delayed until the script returns, meaning we have an active internet connection.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.